# Powershell: PSSQLITE: Complex SQL not supported

Tags: powershell, sqlite

Powershell Version: 5.1
PSSQLITE version: 1.1.0

I have a SQL to run in SQLITE.

1. If I connect via Squirrel SQL, it works fine
2. If I run it in PS with PSSQLIte, the error pops up as below:

```
Invoke-SqliteQuery : Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "SQL logic error or missing database
near "(": syntax error"
At line:11 char:8
+ return Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $sourceDB -Query $sql
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-SqliteQuery
```

Does it mean the pssqlite has limited support for SQL?

Here's my full code for your reference:
**Create Table**

```
CREATE TABLE REVIEW_LOGS(
NUMBER TEXT,
TYPE TEXT,
DATE TEXT,
Reviewee TEXT,
Reviewer TEXT,
TICKET_NUMBER TEXT,
SHORT_DESCRIPTION TEXT,
DURATION INTEGER,
TOPICS_COVERED TEXT,
OUTPUT TEXT,
TO_BE_IMPROVED TEXT,
ACTION_ITEM TEXT,
Adjusted_Issue_Communication TEXT,
ASAT TEXT default current_timestamp
)
```

**Execute SQL in SQLITE**

```
function execute-sql
{
    Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [String]$sql,
            [String]$sourceDB = 'c:\data\cwd\ticketlogs.db'             
    )
    
    try{
            $sql |out-file tttt.log -append
            return Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $sourceDB -Query $sql 
        }catch {
            Write-Host $sql
    }
    
}
```

**The problem SQL**

```
SELECT Metric, count, percentage FROM
(
SELECT Metric, count, percentage, rank() over(PARTITION  by Metric order by count desc) as rank
FROM(
    select Adjusted_Issue_Communication as Metric, count(*)as count , 
              round(count(*)*1.0/(select count(*) from review_logs where date between '2021-01-01'  and '2021-01-31' )*100, 2)|| '%' as percentage
            from review_logs where date between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-31' group by 1 
    Union
    SELECT 'N/A'  as Metric, 0 as count, "0.0%" as percentage 
    Union
    SELECT 'Yes'  as Metric, 0 as count, "0.0%" as percentage 
    Union
    SELECT 'No'  as Metric, 0 as count, "0.0%" as percentage 
    )
)where rank = 1
order by Metric;
```

Comment: How are you sending your sql statement to the function?  Just wondering if not escaping quotes may be an issue

Comment: Hello Daniel, yes i've sent it to the function. I used a here string to the variable $sql and then $result = execute-sql -sql $sql. Even without the function i tried the sql using Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $sourceDB -Query $sql it failed with the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted to use rank() as well and it failed.  Found [this Issue](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSSQLite/issues/29) logged for PSSQLite stating that PS5 version is using the old sqlite binaries that do not include rank and other analytic functions but PS Core binaries were updated.  I tested in Powershell version 7.1.2 and the same command that failed in PS 5.1

```
Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource .\email.db -Query 'select rank() over (partition by Name order by name) as Ranks from email;'
```

worked in Powershell 7.1.2

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Thought it's more related to the PSSQLIte version. It's a lesson to me to do not assume something :)